# Using Firebase database in legacy code with Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-realtime-database, cocoapods

I am working on a legacy iOS app that was developed by another developer, it used Google Cloud messaging for push notifications, I have added Firebase database but I had to disable GCM as I had build issues when Firebase and GCM are added together in the podfile, I am using a separate plist file for Firebase configuration.

I don't have access on GCM app account to migrate to Firebase messaging.

Is there a way to have both GCM and Firebase database work?

Here is the used podfile

```
 pod 'Firebase/Core'
 pod 'Firebase/Auth'
 pod 'Firebase/Database'
 pod 'SDWebImage'
 pod 'PKRevealController'
 pod 'MKNetworkKit'
 pod 'VGParallaxHeader'
 pod 'TTTAttributedLabel'
 pod 'RSBarcodes', '~> 0.1.3'
 pod 'MDHTMLLabel'
 pod 'EAIntroView', '~> 2.9.0'
 pod 'Google/Analytics’
 #pod 'Google/CloudMessaging'
```

If uncommented `#pod 'Google/CloudMessaging` line then xcode (7.3) build will fail giving `duplicate symbols for architecture armv7` errors

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Firebase, you should probably upgrade GCM to [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/).  It's all the same on the inside, except the client SDK should be easier to work with.